# Convert to Date on php it's not working

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$date1 = (string)$_POST['convocatory_open_start_date']; // "30/04/2015"
$date2 = (string)$_POST['convocatory_open_end_date'];  // "31/05/2015"
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
$endDate   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2));
```

but I always get $startDate and $endDate 1970-01-01 Why???

Please Help I have like 3 hours in the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: `strtotime` can't magically handle any and all time values. It does not know that xx/xx/xxxx represents dd/mm/yyyy in your specific case and can't parse it. Use `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Comment: It's does not work, my database always save 1970-01-01 I don't understand why

Comment: What is your DB column's "type"? @Jean Plus, if you have additional DB-related code, show it to us.

Comment: I tried with date and datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you use / as a separator, `strtotime` will assume the format is m/d/Y. So it will not be able to convert it, and it defaults to 1970-01-01.

The easiest solution would be

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1)->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the posted variables :-
$date1 and $date12  are not **NULL**
Because `NULL` is interpreted as 0 by the php function `strtotime()`, since you are supposed to  pass an integer **timestamp**. A timestamp of **0** means **1-1-1970**.

You need to check the posted contents of the posted variables

```
if(($date1 === NULL) || ($date1 === NULL) ) {
//don't use `strtotime()`
 }
```

If that is not the case and Your variables are posted, the only thing i can think of is that you have problem with the stringTimeFormatting  when using the date function and you input format.

```
$date1 = (string)$_POST['convocatory_open_start_date']; // "30/04/2015"
$date2 = (string)$_POST['convocatory_open_end_date'];  // "31/05/2015"

$startDate = date($date1);
$endDate   = date($date2);
echo $startDate, '<br/> ' , $endDate;
```

Hope that adds some to your Quest!